# NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am trying to run a recently upgraded app and now I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.newLinkedHashMap(I)Ljava/util/LinkedHashMap;
```

While trying to run the following code...

```
public void truncateTable() {
    jdbcTemplate.call(conn -> conn.prepareCall("{ call ...MyFunc() }"), new ArrayList<>());
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions of spring that won't work.

Comment: I got the same error because during the upgrade I forgot to remove an old version of spring-jcl-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar. After I fixed that, it worked.